# Make a playlist collaborative using the Spotify Apps API

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to make a playlist collaborative using the Spotify Apps API?

The Playlist object in javascript has a Collaborative attribute but this is, i think, only for checking the current collaborative status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you set the attribute to true and it will be a collaborative playlist but I guess you have to have permissions to the playlist for it to work.
I tried this and it worked for a playlist I created.

```
p = models.Playlist.fromURI('spotify-uri');
p.data.collaborative = true;
```

After this the playlist was shown as a collaborative playlist in my client.